# Create Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, programming-languages

```
index = {'California': 2000, 'California': 2010, 'New York': 2000, 'New York': 2010, 'Texas': 2000, 'Texas': 2010}
```

`population=[23434,56566,76766,546546,45345,56546`]

Any method to create data frame in python(pandas) like this:

```
state Year population 
California  2000 23434 
            2010 56566 
New York    2000 76766 
            2010 546546 
Texas       2000 45345 
            2010 56546
```

Please write complete code to create dataframe in python

Comment: Your `index` is broken, because dictionary has duplicated keys, are necessary unique

Comment: No,there is way to create dataframe using pd.multiindex.But I don't know how to implement

Comment: Show your efforts like I'm using this library and here is my code and this giving me this kind of error not directly asking about how to do that.

Comment: Some problem with my solution?

Answer (score 3):

Your index is broken, because dictionary has always unique keys in python.

For `MultiIndex` is possible use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), but length of `MultiIndex` has to be same like length of `population` list:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['California','New York','Texas'], 
                                  [2000, 2010]], names=['state', 'year'])
population=[23434,56566,76766,546546,45345,56546]
df = pd.DataFrame({'population':population}, index=mux)
print (df)
                 population
state      year            
California 2000       23434
           2010       56566
New York   2000       76766
           2010      546546
Texas      2000       45345
           2010       56546
```

---

```
print (len(mux))
6
print (len(population))
6
```

Comment: You can get the name of index by mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['California','New York','Texas'], [2000, 2010]], names=['state', 'year'])